# Apache2 won't start - Mac OS X - Passenger

Tags: apache, macos, system-administration, passenger

I've installed passenger a little while back and when I restarted my mac tonight, Apache2 won't start.

Here is what I get.

Anyone have any ideas? Re-install Apache2?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 78: 10530 Trace/BPT trap          $HTTPD $ARGV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the module was compiled for the wrong architecture. As trivial as it might seem, try uninstalling passenger to see whether this was the problem and then try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that module isn't installed correctly. Try disabling it in your apache configuration (in /etc/apache2/)

Comment: i might have bigger issues than I thought:

-bash: a2dismod: command not found

Comment: Yeah, that script wouldn't be present. I've updated my answer accordingly.